# Android Studio JSON parsing error throws an JSONException

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse this JSON and throws an JSONException error when it goes back to the for sentence from the jsonBranch
I dont know what is throwing the that error an crash the app.
I tried changing the parameter of the for sentence but it doenst work.

### JSON

```
[
   {
      "idBranchRestaurant":1,
      "idRestaurant":1,
      "restaurant":{
         "idRestaurant":1,
         "name":"Don Julio",
         "description":"La mejor parrilla para cualquier turista",
         "socialNetwork":[
            {
               "idSocialNetworkRestaurant":1,
               "idRestaurant":1,
               "idTypeSocialNetwork":1,
               "value":"www.donjulio.com.ar",
               "type":{
                  "idTypeSocialNetwork":1,
                  "name":"Website",
                  "icon":"website_ic.jpg"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "idRangePriceBranch":1,
      "RangePrice":{
         "idRangePriceBranch":1,
         "idBranchRestaurant":1,
         "minimum":300,
         "maximum":600
      },
      "name":"Paraguay",
      "photo":[
         {
            "idBranchPhoto":4,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idUser":0,
            "photo":"entradaDonJulio.jpg"
         }
      ],
      "cuisine":[
         {
            "idCousine":1,
            "name":"Parrilla"
         }
      ],
      "menu":[
         {
            "idTypeMenu":1,
            "name":"Mediodia",
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "plates":null
         },
         {
            "idTypeMenu":2,
            "name":"Noche",
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "plates":null
         }
      ],
      "filter":[
         {
            "idTypeFilter":2,
            "name":"Family",
            "icon":"family_ic.jpg"
         }
      ],
      "service":[
         {
            "idService":2,
            "name":"Comida para celiacos"
         },
         {
            "idService":1,
            "name":"Wifi"
         }
      ],
      "timetable":[
         {
            "idTimetableBranch":11,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idDay":2,
            "openingHour":"19 hs",
            "closingHour":"24 hs",
            "day":{
               "idDay":2,
               "name":"Tuesday"
            }
         },
         {
            "idTimetableBranch":10,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idDay":2,
            "openingHour":"12 hs",
            "closingHour":"16 hs",
            "day":{
               "idDay":2,
               "name":"Tuesday"
            }
         },
         {
            "idTimetableBranch":9,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idDay":1,
            "openingHour":"19 hs",
            "closingHour":"24 hs",
            "day":{
               "idDay":1,
               "name":"Monday"
            }
         },
         {
            "idTimetableBranch":8,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idDay":1,
            "openingHour":"12 hs ",
            "closingHour":"16 hs",
            "day":{
               "idDay":1,
               "name":"Monday"
            }
         },
         {
            "idTimetableBranch":12,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idDay":3,
            "openingHour":"12 hs",
            "closingHour":"16 hs",
            "day":{
               "idDay":3,
               "name":"Wednesday"
            }
         },
         {
            "idTimetableBranch":13,
            "idBranchRestaurant":1,
            "idDay":3,
            "openingHour":"19 hs ",
            "closingHour":"24 hs",
            "day":{
               "idDay":3,
               "name":"Wednesday"
            }
         },
         {
        "idTimetableBranch":14,
        "idBranchRestaurant":1,
        "idDay":4,
        "openingHour":"12 hs",
        "closingHour":"16 hs",
        "day":{
           "idDay":4,
           "name":"Thursday"
        }
     },
     {
        "idTimetableBranch":15,
        "idBranchRestaurant":1,
        "idDay":4,
        "openingHour":"19 hs",
        "closingHour":"24 hs",
        "day":{
           "idDay":4,
           "name":"Thursday"
        }
     },
     {
        "idTimetableBranch":16,
        "idBranchRestaurant":1,
        "idDay":5,
        "openingHour":"12 hs",
        "closingHour":"16 hs ",
        "day":{
           "idDay":5,
           "name":"Friday"
        }
     },
     {
        "idTimetableBranch":17,
        "idBranchRestaurant":1,
        "idDay":5,
        "openingHour":"19 hs ",
        "closingHour":"2 hs",
        "day":{
           "idDay":5,
           "name":"Friday"
        }
     }
  ],
  "latitude":"87654322",
  "longitude":"23456789",
  "averageCalification":4.0,
  "promotion":[
     {
        "idPromotion":3,
        "idTypePromotion":2,
        "code":"DIADELPADRE",
        "name":"Dia Del Padre Regalo",
        "startDate":"2017-06-26T00:00:00",
        "expireDate":"2017-06-18T00:00:00",
        "description":"postre de regalo",
        "value":100,
        "type":{
           "idTypePromotion":2,
           "name":"Gift"
        }
     }
  ]


 }
]
```

### Android Class

```
private class BranchGetAll extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Branch>> {

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Branch> datos) {
        super.onPostExecute(datos);
        if (datos != null){
            listRestaurant.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resAdapter.setmRestaurantData(datos);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(main,"Error connection database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Branch> doInBackground(String... parametros) {
        String url = parametros[0] + parametros[1] + "/" + parametros[2];
        int limit = Integer.parseInt(parametros[1]);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        String resultado;
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();  // Llamo al API Rest servicio1 en ejemplo.com
            resultado = response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());             // Error de Network
            return null;
        }

        try{
            ArrayList<Branch> branchList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonBranch = new JSONArray(resultado);

            Branch b = new Branch();

            // se traba al realizar segunda vuelta
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonBranch.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = jsonBranch.getJSONObject(i);
                b.idBranch = obj.getInt("idBranchRestaurant");
                JSONObject resto = obj.getJSONObject("restaurant");
                b.restaurant.idRestaurant = resto.getInt("idRestaurant");
                b.restaurant.name = resto.getString("name");
                b.restaurant.description = resto.getString("description");
                JSONArray socialNetwork = resto.getJSONArray("socialNetwork");
                ArrayList<SocialNetwork> list = new ArrayList<SocialNetwork>();
                for (int j = 0; j < socialNetwork.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject social = socialNetwork.getJSONObject(j);
                    SocialNetwork sn = new SocialNetwork();
                    sn.idSocialNetwork = social.getInt("idSocialNetworkRestaurant");
                    JSONObject typeSocial = social.getJSONObject("type");
                    sn.name = typeSocial.getString("name");
                    sn.value = social.getString("value");
                    list.add(sn);
                }
                b.restaurant.social = list;
                JSONObject rangeObj = obj.getJSONObject("RangePrice");
                b.range.idRangePrice = rangeObj.getInt("idRangePriceBranch");
                b.range.maximum = rangeObj.getInt("maximum");
                b.range.minimum = rangeObj.getInt("minimum");
                b.name = obj.getString("name");
                JSONArray photo = obj.getJSONArray("photo");
                ArrayList<PhotoBranch> listPhoto = new ArrayList<PhotoBranch>();
                for (int k = 0; k < photo.length(); k++){
                    JSONObject photoObj = photo.getJSONObject(k);
                    PhotoBranch p = new PhotoBranch();
                    p.idPhoto = photoObj.getInt("idBranchPhoto");
                    p.idUser = photoObj.getInt("idUser");
                    p.photo = photoObj.getString("photo");
                    listPhoto.add(p);
                }
                b.photo = listPhoto;
                JSONArray cuisine = obj.getJSONArray("cuisine");
                ArrayList<Cuisine> listCuisine = new ArrayList<Cuisine>();
                for (int c = 0; c < cuisine.length(); c++){
                    JSONObject cuisineObj = cuisine.getJSONObject(c);
                    Cuisine cn = new Cuisine();
                    cn.idCuisine = cuisineObj.getInt("idCousine");
                    cn.name = cuisineObj.getString("name");
                    listCuisine.add(cn);
                }
                b.cuisine = listCuisine;
                JSONArray menu = obj.getJSONArray("menu");
                ArrayList<Menu> listMenu = new ArrayList<Menu>();
                for (int m = 0; m < menu.length(); m++){
                    JSONObject menuObj = menu.getJSONObject(m);
                    Menu mn = new Menu();
                    mn.idMenu = menuObj.getInt("idTypeMenu");
                    mn.type = menuObj.getString("name");
                }
                JSONArray filter = obj.getJSONArray("filter");
                ArrayList<Filter> listFilter = new ArrayList<Filter>();
                for (int f = 0; f < filter.length(); f++){
                    JSONObject filterObj = filter.getJSONObject(f);
                    Filter ft = new Filter();
                    ft.idFilter = filterObj.getInt("idTypeFilter");
                    ft.name = filterObj.getString("name");
                    ft.icon = filterObj.getString("icon");
                    listFilter.add(ft);
                }
                b.filter = listFilter;
                JSONArray service = obj.getJSONArray("service");
                ArrayList<Service> listService = new ArrayList<Service>();
                for (int s = 0; s < service.length(); s++) {
                    JSONObject svObj = service.getJSONObject(s);
                    Service sv = new Service();
                    sv.idService = svObj.getInt("idService");
                    sv.name = svObj.getString("name");
                    listService.add(sv);
                }
                b.service = listService;
                JSONArray timetable = obj.getJSONArray("timetable");
                ArrayList<Timetable> listTimetable = new ArrayList<Timetable>();
                for(int t = 0; t < timetable.length(); t++) {
                    JSONObject ttObj = timetable.getJSONObject(t);
                    Timetable tt = new Timetable();
                    tt.idTimetable = ttObj.getInt("idTimetableBranch");
                    tt.openingHours = ttObj.getString("openingHour");
                    tt.closingHours = ttObj.getString("closingHour");
                    JSONObject dayObj = ttObj.getJSONObject("day");
                    tt.Day = dayObj.getString("name");
                    listTimetable.add(tt);
                }
                b.timetable = listTimetable;
                b.latitude = obj.getString("latitude");
                b.longitude = obj.getString("longitude");
                b.averageCalification = obj.getInt("averageCalification");
                JSONArray promotion = obj.getJSONArray("promotion");
                ArrayList<Promotion> listPromotion = new ArrayList<Promotion>();
                for (int p = 0; p < promotion.length(); p++){
                    JSONObject pObj = promotion.getJSONObject(p);
                    Promotion prom = new Promotion();
                    prom.idPromotion = pObj.getInt("idPromotion");
                    prom.code = pObj.getString("code");
                    prom.name = pObj.getString("name");
                    prom.startDate = Utility.convertStringToCalendar(pObj.getString("startDate"));
                    prom.expireDate = Utility.convertStringToCalendar(pObj.getString("expireDate"));
                    prom.description = pObj.getString("description");
                    prom.value = pObj.getInt("value");
                    JSONObject type = pObj.getJSONObject("type");
                    prom.TypePromotion = type.getString("name");
                    listPromotion.add(prom);
                }
                b.promotion = listPromotion;
                branchList.add(b);
            }
            return branchList;
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

### Stack trace

```
06-29 21:51:00.934 7533-7533/com.morfando.android.morfando E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.morfando.android.morfando, PID: 7533
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.morfando.android.morfando.Restaurant.Adapter.RestaurantAdapter$NumberViewHolder.bind(RestaurantAdapter.java:97)
                                                                                 at com.morfando.android.morfando.Restaurant.Adapter.RestaurantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RestaurantAdapter.java:61)
                                                                                 at com.morfando.android.morfando.Restaurant.Adapter.RestaurantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RestaurantAdapter.java:23)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
06-29 21:51:00.946 7533-7533/com.morfando.android.morfando E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: show us the stacktrace and which line of code is causing the trouble

Comment: @ScaryWombat i just add the stacktrace and the line is this one for (int i = 0; i < jsonBranch.length(); i++)

Comment: Nothing to do with JSON processing, the String is null

Comment: It's obvious. Look at line 97 of `RestaurantAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a library called GSON.

GSON automatically converts JSON into Java POJOs.

Comment: It is more difficult to because my Branch class has attributes from other class.

Comment: @MatiasFinkelstein It'll be really helpful if you show us the stacktrace.

Comment: @Hitesh i just add it

Comment: @MatiasFinkelstein There is nothing wrong with the parsing. If you want us to point us to the exact problem, please post the code for RestaurantAdapter and the place where you are setting it.